# Flutter custom tabs like image

Tags: flutter, tabs

how can we create a custom tab like bellow image in Flutter ?

[image]

I searched and saw many custom tabs but any of them did not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you create a List, where you will specify your tab Items, with
  color, name and so on. It would be better to create a model for that
  and hold them in a List.
- Then you generate a Horizontal Scrollable-Listview. And you will wrap each ListView with an InkWell, so they are "Tab-able". also They have to be wrapped within a container, where you give them on the top lieft and right a rounded border and the color you wish
- Then create a Container with height of 2 and update its color, based on the tablist-item color.
- If you also want to be more advanced, you can take an Animated Container instead of a normal Container for the Listview-Items, so you can change its size when its tapped. This will need a lot of fine tuning.

With this cookbook you can build your own.

Comment: Thank you bro , I write a code with your guidance and put it here in an aswer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MrOrhan I create my tabs with bellow code

```
Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            height: 50.0,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () => homeProvider.setTabIndex(0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(
                                  10.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: homeProvider.tabs[0].color,
                            ),
                            width: 100,
                            height: homeProvider.tabIndex == 0 ? 50 : 40,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              homeProvider.tabs[0].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () => homeProvider.setTabIndex(1),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(
                                  10.0,
                                ),
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(
                                  10.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: homeProvider.tabs[1].color,
                            ),
                            width: 150,
                            height: homeProvider.tabIndex == 1 ? 50 : 40,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              homeProvider.tabs[1].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () => homeProvider.setTabIndex(2),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(
                                  10.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: homeProvider.tabs[2].color,
                            ),
                            width: 150,
                            height: homeProvider.tabIndex == 2 ? 50 : 40,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              homeProvider.tabs[2].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 0.0,
                color: homeProvider.tabs[homeProvider.tabIndex].color,
              ),
              color: homeProvider.tabs[homeProvider.tabIndex].color,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            height: 5.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
```

and the output is like bellow

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE** : The Code has Updated to disappear little gap btween the tabs and the container below it

Comment: This looking very good. you can change small details. there is a little gap btween the tabs and the container below it. Try to remove it -> by removing the sizedbox around the container (you can directly set the container hight to 5). if this not working try to -> set container padding to endgeinset.zero. If this also not works, I will try it and write you a comment.

Comment: thank you a lot , I removed SizedBox and set the Container padding to EdgeInsets.zero , But that gap still here

Comment: Can you also set the padding of the Container wich is holding your Listview wo edgeInset.zero? If this also not helps, set the border width from the upper container to 0 and also from the bottom container. And if that also not helpes, set also the bottom border color from the upper container to the same as the selected button and the border from the bottom container the the color of selected button

Comment: @MrOrhan Thank you man , set the with of bottom container and set it's border color to homeProvider.tabs[homeProvider.tabIndex].color solved the problem

Comment: You welcome. Can you update your code, so if some one has the same problem, can take look in your code :) ? And can I have maybe some thumbs up as well ? :D